# Почему всегда 1 в echo $select?

Tags: php, переменные

Добрый день!

Подскажите, почему всегда 1 в echo $select в Shablonist.php?

[Shablonist.php](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8w9w07H1SsdeDIyVlU5TUU2elU/edit?usp=sharing)
[patternSelection.html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8w9w07H1SsddXdURXl5MUI2UWM/edit?usp=sharing)
[1T.html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8w9w07H1SsdTUlSejRkTC1IdlU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @mkrichet, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@mkrichet](/users/22396/mkrichet)](/users/22396/mkrichet) - в прошлый раз, я вам даже рефакторинг кода сделал, а вы все равно продолжаете говнокодить...

У вас какая-то чушь.

```
<input type="hidden" name='s' value='1'>
```

Прям предвкушаю следующий вопрос: а как передать параметр, который был выбран на прошлом шаге.

Comment: Так шаблон то выбирается!!! Т.е. $select меняет свое значение
<option value="1">Мошенничество</option>
<option value="2">БЛОКИРОВКА КАРТЫ</option>